# Idris Leap Year Test Implementation

Tags: idris

I've built the following isLeapYear function in Idris:

```
module Leap
import Data.Nat

partial
isDivisibleByFour : Nat -> Bool
isDivisibleByFour (year) = (modNat year 4) == 0

partial 
isNotDivisibleByOneHundred : Nat -> Bool
isNotDivisibleByOneHundred(year) = (modNat year 100) /= 0

partial
isDivisibleByFourHundred : Nat -> Bool
isDivisibleByFourHundred(year) = (modNat year 400) == 0



partial
isLeapYear : Nat -> Bool
isLeapYear (year) = (isDivisibleByFour year) && ((isNotDivisibleByOneHundred year) || (isDivisibleByFourHundred year))
```

This works correctly and it's fine but it feels a bit hacky to have to break out `isDivisibleByFour`, `isNotDivisibleByOneHundred` and `isDivisibleByFourHundred`. I mean I thought I could define functions inside other functions with the `let` keyword.  But that only seems to work for one subfunction; I can't figure out how to define all three or how to code this so that I don't need subfunctions.  Can anyone suggest how I should modify this code so that I don't have to have "visible" tests for division by 4, 100 and 400?

Comment: It feels like you want a single isDivisbleBy function that accepts a natural number, right? What aspect of Irdris made that hard? (And then negation is a one-off that caller can worry about, outside of the pattern.)

Comment: I was trying to use `let` within the function definition to capture the three tests (divisible by 4, divisible by 100, divisible by 400).  Oh but I think I see what you're saying about the one-off of negation.